# Why is google street view published video status always pending?

Tags: api, upload, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

everyone

I just encountered a weird problem with google streetview published video.

when ever i publish a video it always has status `pending`, but got no error or info why is it `pending`.

can anyone please explain, why would the processing is not starting for the video?

NOTE: video is created by images and video contains gps data and on upload it prompts for a gpx file which i also provided, upload completes with no error, yet the status is pending.

Answer (score -1):

It should change from pending to processing after a short time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).